# How to fit map to tile layer bounds in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map. The map container is very big compared to the tile in first zoom level (256px X 256px). I want to get the bounds of tile and fit the map bounds to it. I am able to `fitbound()` with multiple markers. I adopted the code from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/deciob/vVdyM/26/) . I tried to achieve fit to tile also with same idea. unfortunately it doesn't seem working. Here is my code

```
     var fitToBounds = function () {
         //getting bound of tile 256X256 pixel
        var maxLat = map.unproject(new L.Point(0,0)).lat; 
        var maxLat = map.unproject(new L.Point(0,256)).lat;
        var maxLng = map.unproject(new L.Point(256,0)).lng;
        var minLng = map.unproject(new L.Point(256,256)).lng;
        var southWest = new L.LatLng(minLat, minLng);
        var northEast = new L.LatLng(maxLat, maxLng);
        map.fitBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));
    };
```

Comment: You have two var called maxLat... one should be minLat

Answer (score 4):

Group your markers in a `L.mapbox.featureGroup()` and then on your `map` use

```
map.fitBounds(featureGroup.getBounds());
```

Feature groups are like a `layerGroup` but also has a `.getBounds()` method that can be used to set your fit. See [the docs.](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup)

Comment: He don't say anything about markers. He have tile layer, and Tilelayer doesn't have getBounds method.  Your idea about grouping markers doesn't help anything.

Answer (score 4):

maybe not the best solution, but at least working:
Add an other layer and make it invisible. Zoom to this one. Advantage is, you might also add *onEachFeature*.

```
     var pointsWithBounds=[]
     _.each(layerWithoutBounds, function (element) {
                pointsWithBounds.push(
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "CircleMarker",
                            "coordinates": [element.lon, element.lat]
                     });
      });
      var layerWithBounds = L.geoJSON(pointsWithBounds, {
                style: {
                          fillColor: 'transparent',
                          color: 'transparent'
                       }
            });
      layerWithBounds.addTo(map)
      map.setView(layerWithBounds.getBounds().getCenter());
      map.fitBounds(layerWithBounds.getBounds());
```